# How to write test for FastAPI with postgresql

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi, endpoint

I'm confused looking for a solution for my app how to write test for endpoints and functions.

I havn't 'post' endpoint with classic inserting data into db, but my endpoint starts function where script looks for files in directrory, creates dataframe and after locking df and some calculations inserts data into database.

And I don't know how to write tests for that case. It's difficult for me to insert some "fake" data into db to read them in different test (testing get endpoint) and checks if they are ok.

**this is my db.py**

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from contextlib import contextmanager

'''Creating sqlalchemy engine and sessionmaker'''

load_dotenv(".env")
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = os.environ["DATABASE_URL"]
DB_TIMEOUT = os.environ["DB_TIMEOUT"]
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, connect_args={
                       'connect_timeout': DB_TIMEOUT})

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

@contextmanager
def get_session():
    """Provide a transactional scope around a series of operations."""
    session = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()
```

**my endpoints:**

**-/impala/update: GET endpoint runs update database (update_data as backgroud_tasks imports files and cr
eates dataframe and after that creates Database object and runs impala module in it)**

**-/impala: GET endpoint lists all data**

```
@impala_api.get("/impala/update", include_in_schema=False)
async def impalaDataUpdate(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    '''route to run update process if there is no current update in progress.
    Update is running as a separated task in backgroud to give user
    intermidiate answer that update is in progress'''
    global status
    if status != True:
        background_tasks.add_task(update_data)
    status = True
    return {"impala update": "in progress refresh website after view minutes"}


@impala_api.get("/impala", response_model=List[schema.Impala], response_model_exclude_none=True, tags=["Impala"])
async def impala_all():
    """
     endpoint: lists all impalas data, including filters and bearings lists with all replacements datas
    """
    if response := db.session.query(Impala).order_by(Impala.unit).all():
        return response
    elif status is True:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=403,
            detail='Impala update in progress',
        )
    else:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=404,
            detail='Not found',
        )
```

**and this is insert_into_db.py**

```
from impala_api.models_Impala import Impala as Imp
from impala_api.models_Impala import ImpalaDetails as Impd
from fastapi_sqlalchemy import db
from pandas import DataFrame
from sqlalchemy import func
from datetime import date


class Database:
    def __init__(self, df: DataFrame, unit: str) -> None:
        self.df = df
        self.unit = unit

    def assign_data(self, row, exists):
        '''assigning data into query from dataframe row'''
        exists.unit = row["unit"]
        exists.Black = row["Black"]
        exists.Cyan = row["Cyan"]
        exists.Magenta = row["Magenta"]
        exists.Yellow = row["Yellow"]
        exists.White = row["White"]
        exists.Squaremeter = row["Squaremeter"]
        exists.Total_Ink = row["Total_Ink"]
        exists.date = row["date"]


    def impala(self):
        '''commit data into impala table in db'''
        summed_data = db.session.query(func.sum(Impd.printed).label('sum_printed'), func.sum(
            Impd.ink).label('sum_ink')).filter(Impd.unit == self.unit).first()
        if (
            exists := db.session.query(Imp).filter(Imp.unit == self.unit).first()
        ):
            exists.suma_m2 = int(summed_data.sum_printed)
            exists.suma_ml = int(summed_data.sum_ink)
            exists.date = date.today()
        else:
            impala_data = Imp(
                unit=self.unit,
                suma_m2=int(summed_data.sum_printed),
                suma_ml=int(summed_data.sum_ink),
                date=date.today()
            )
            db.session.add(impala_data)
        db.session.commit()
```

can you help me how to do it correctly?

First of all I think I should add some test data into db using "/impala/update" endpoint and then when testing "/impala" endpoint reading them get passed test for this endpoint - but correct me if I'm wrong.

Anyway I dont know how to do it correctly